# How to add title, background, and border as svg external images to a cloned element of d3js tree to be downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, background-image

I have a d3js tree which I am able to download, I want to add a title, Arabesque background and Arabesque border from external .svg files for a better visual effect.

I have 3 external files: title_3.png (later I will use an svg equivalent), background-F4EED7.svg, and border_1.svg.  I need to center the title to the middle of the graph and allow the height of the title to be resized according to the length and depth of the generated tree.

What would be the best way of achieving this?

```js
var treeData = [{
  "name": "Top Level",
  "parent": "null",
  "remark": "yes",
  "children": [{
      "name": "Level 2: A",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "yes",
      "children": [{
          "name": "Son of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        },
        {
          "name": "Daughter of A",
          "parent": "Level 2: A",
          "remark": "null"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Level 2: B",
      "parent": "Top Level",
      "remark": "null"
    }
  ]
}];

//*************************************************************************************
// 1. Create the button
var button = document.createElement("button");
button.innerHTML = "download file";
//*************************************************************************************

// ************** Generate the tree diagram  *****************
var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 120,
    bottom: 20,
    left: 120
  },
  width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var i = 0,
  rectW = 100,
  rectH = 30,
  duration = 750,
  root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
  .size([height, width]);

//swap x and y for vertical
var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
  .projection(function(d) {
    return [d.x + rectW / 2, d.y + rectH / 2];
  });

var gElement = document.createElementNS(d3.ns.prefix.svg, 'g');
gElement.setAttribute("id", "fg");
console.log(gElement);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append(function() {
    return gElement;
  }) //The argument to .append() has to be a function, you can't just pass element to it.
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

root = treeData[0];
root.x0 = height / 2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
    links = tree.links(nodes);

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 180;
  });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
    .data(nodes, function(d) {
      return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
    });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  //swap x and y for vertical
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")";
    })
    .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
    //nodeEnter.append("circle")
    //  .attr("r", 1e-6)
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeEnter.append("text")
    .attr("x", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13;
    })
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", function(d) {
      return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
    })
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.name;
    })
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Filter to put tooltip only on nodes that have information associated with it
  var nodesWithInfo = nodeEnter.filter(function(d) {
    return (d.remark != 'null')
  })
  nodesWithInfo
    .append("circle")
    .attr("export-ignore", true)
    .attr("cx", 96)
    .attr("cy", 7)
    .attr("r", 10);

  nodesWithInfo
    .append("text")
    .attr("export-ignore", true)
    .attr("id", "infoText")
    .attr("x", 96)
    .attr("y", 7)
    .attr("dy", ".30em")
    .style("font-style", "italic")
    .style("font-family", "serif")
    .style("font-weight", "bold")
    .text("i");

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  //swap x and y for vertical layout
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

  //nodeUpdate.select("circle")
  nodeUpdate.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("stroke", "black")
    //  .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", function(d) {
      return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
    });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
    .attr("x", rectW / 2)
    .attr("y", rectH / 2)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  //vertical switch x and y positions
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + source.x + "," + source.y + ")";
    })
    .remove();

  nodeExit.select("rect")
    .attr("width", rectW)
    .attr("height", rectH)
    .style("stroke", "black");
  //  .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
    .data(links, function(d) {
      return d.target.id;
    });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("stroke", "#ccc")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x0,
        y: source.y0
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", function(d) {
      var o = {
        x: source.x,
        y: source.y
      };
      return diagonal({
        source: o,
        target: o
      });
    })
    .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

}

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

//*************************************************************************************
// 2. Append button somewhere
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
body.appendChild(button)
  .setAttribute("transform", "translate(" + 0 + "," + 0 + ")");

//*************************************************************************************

function svgDataURL(svg) {
  var svgAsXML = (new XMLSerializer).serializeToString(svg);
  var dataURL = "data:image/svg+xml," + encodeURIComponent(svgAsXML);
  return dataURL;
}

button.onclick = function() {
  var svgElement = document.querySelector('svg');
  var svgWH = svgElement.getBBox();

  var canvasWidth = svgWH.width;
  var canvasHeight = svgWH.height;

  var groupElement = document.getElementById('fg');
  groupElement.setAttribute("transform", "translate(0,0)");

  const bb = groupElement.getBBox();

  //Title of the tree
  var svgimg = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'image');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, 'height', "30");
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, 'width', bb.width / 2);
  svgimg.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'href', 'http://localhost/images/Title3.png');
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, 'x', '-' + rectW / 2);
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, 'y', '-' + rectH / 2);
  svgimg.setAttributeNS(null, 'visibility', 'visible');

  //Background SVG pattern
  svgBgImg.style.backgroundImage = "url('http://localhost/images/background-F4EED7.svg')";

  // clone the svg to avoid destroying it while appending to the svg namespace
  let clonedGroupElement = groupElement.cloneNode(true);

  var svgContent = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');

  svgContent.setAttribute('viewBox', ' ' + bb.x + ' ' + bb.y + '  ' + bb.width + ' ' + bb.height);

  svgContent.setAttribute("width", "100%");
  svgContent.setAttribute("height", "100%");
  svgContent.setAttribute("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

  // try to remove the information icon before downloading
  clonedGroupElement.querySelectorAll('[export-ignore]').forEach(function(node) {
    node.remove();
  });

  clonedGroupElement.style.borderImageSource = "url('http://localhost/images/border_1.svg')";
  clonedGroupElement.append(svgimg);
          clonedGroupElement.style.borderImageSource = "url('http://localhost/images/border_1.svg')";

  svgContent.appendChild(clonedGroupElement); // use the cloned nodes

  var dl = document.createElement('a');
  document.body.appendChild(dl);
  dl.setAttribute("href", svgDataURL(svgContent)); // function svgDataURL expects a node
  dl.setAttribute("download", "test.svg");
  dl.click();
  dl.remove();

  svgContent.removeChild(clonedGroupElement);
};
```

```css
<style>.node {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.node circle {
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1px;
}

.node text {
  font: 12px sans-serif;
}

.link {
  /*
      fill: none;
      stroke: #ccc;
      stroke-width: 2px;*/
}

</style>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.4/d3.min.js"></script>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>Tree Example</title>
</head>

<body>
```

Comment: Add them in, as your would any other element, while you're generating the svg at your line starting `var svg =`.

Comment: @Ouroborus I would like to add these to the cloned group element if possible, so the screen remains the same and the title, border and background appear on the downloaded svg file for printing.

Comment: I don't see where you're cloning a group. But the process is still the same: After cloning the group, add the elements to that clone.